# System.Web.Extensions 3.5.0.0 with .NET 3.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

Is it possible to use System.Web.Extensions 3.5 without upgrading to .NET 3.5?  We are using .NET 3.0 and have been asked to upgrade from web extensions 1.0 to 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

To be perfectly clear:
.Net 3.0 and 3.5 are simply additions to the existing 2.0 framework.  The versioning MS did is somewhat of a misnomer.  .Net 4.0 is, however, an actual framework change.

For confirmation, IIS (and anything else) sees your application as a 2.0 app.

That said, there is no reason NOT to go ahead and "upgrade" the server to have 3.5 available.  You can run multiple apps on the machine each at their own framework level.

Now, if your application references 3.0 specific libraries and you want it to use a 3.5 assembly, then you will need to change the web.config and assembly manifest to point to the 3.5 versions.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you don't upgrade to 3.5 you will not have the assemblies to reference. Quite simple.

Comment: Acutally, you can install 3.5 and use the web extensions without upgrading an application to .NET 3.5.  There is a difference between installing 3.5 and referencing it in an application.

Comment: Thanks for the obvious answer though.  Could an actual software engineer or architect answer this.

Comment: If your question was a little less ambiguous you might have gotten the answer you wanted. I just work with what you give me. Tell me, do you plan to cart around 3.5 assemblies with your app? You see, they are not INSTALLED on the machine with 3.0.... If so, I wish you luck. And BTW, you snide remark is noted and discarded.